# Union of three independent events

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let  $ A_1, A_2, A_3 $ be independent events with probabilities $ \frac 12,\frac13,\frac14,$ respectively. How to compute for  $P(A_1\cup A_2 \cup A_3).$

My solution starts from using the probability of their complements, I do not know how to answer this question. Please help.

$P(A_1\cup A_2 \cup A_3) = 1- P(A_1^c\cap A_2^c \cap A_3^c)$

Comment: Why don't you write down the part you've already done?

Comment: I already edited my solution

Comment: That's a good start. Are there any assumptions under which you would be able to calculate $P(A_1^c \cap A_2^c \cap A_3^c)$?

Comment: getting the complements of the events first

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: its $\frac12,\frac23, \frac34$

Comment: You mean $P(A_1^c) = 1/2$, $P(A_2^c) = 2/3$, $P(A_3^c) = 3/4$, right?

Comment: Also asked at http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/117824/10259

Answer (score 1):

$P(A_1\cup A_2 \cup A_3)= P(A_1\cup A_2) + P(A_3) - P((A_1\cup A_2)\cap A_3 )$
$=P(A_1\cup A_2) + P(A_3) - P(A_1\cup A_2).P(A_3 )$ ..since $(A_1\cup A_2)$ and $(A_3)$  are independent

Similarly,
$P(A_1\cup A_2)=P(A_1)+P(A_2)-P(A_1\cap A_2)=P(A_1)+P(A_2) - P(A_1).P(A_2)$

Now you can just do the calculation. I guess the final answer is 3/4

Comment: First the formula for P(A∪B∪C) is known in full generality. Second this is definitely not the most efficient approach.

Comment: @Did - As far as efficient approach is concerned, are you talking about $$P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3) = 1 - P( (A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3)^c) = 1- P(A_1^c \cap A_2^c \cap A_3^c) = 1 - P(A_1^c).P(A_2^c).P(A_3^c)$$  Btw, not sure what do you mean by " First the formula for P(A∪B∪C) is known in full generality "

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. That the formula for the probability of a union is known in full generality as the alternated sum of the probabilities of the events, minus the sum of the probabilities of the two-by-two intersections, plus the sum of the probabilities of the three-by-three intersections, etc., except that starting from three events there is no "etc." And also that your answer seems to be left incomplete (one expects that you wuold collect every term to get the full formula for P(A∪B∪C) but you don't...)

Answer (score -1):

Use the following fact

> If $A$ and $B$ are independent events, then $A^{c}$ and $B^{c}$ are independent evetns

**Proof:** We see that 
$$P(A^c\cap B^c)=P(A^c)+P(B^c)-P(A^c\cup B^c)=P(A^c)+P(B^c)-P((A\cap B)^c)=$$
$$P(A^c)+P(B^c)-(1-P(A\cap B))$$
which since $A$ and $B$ are independent then we have 
$$=P(A^c)+P(B^c)-(1-P(A)P(B))=(1-P(A))+(1-P(B))-(1-P(A)P(B))=$$
$$1-P(A)-P(B)+P(B)P(A)= (1-P(A))(1-P(B))=P(A^c)P(B^c)$$

Thus $A^c$ and $B^c$ are independent

Comment: This fact, while true, is not enough to solve the exercise.

Comment: Well doesn't the definition of independence with this  just convert $P(A_1^c \cap A_2^c \cap A_3^c)=P(A_1^c)P(A_2^c)P(A_3^c)$

Comment: No, the independence of 3 events is not reducible to 2-by-2 independences.

Comment: So it's not true if for three events that each are mutually/ pair wise independent that the 3 events are independent

Comment: Indeed. $ $ $ $

Comment: Man haven't done this material in awhile I gues have to review that concept again

Comment: Thinking about it now I can think of counter examples. Just from first thought its seems counter intuitive. Thanks for pointing that out!